# How to pass value from one form to another form on submiting it?

Tags: php, forms

I am working on one application where i have one drop down menu whose value is selected.

```
<form action="metaGeneratePlot.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
<br><br>
Please select the sheet:
<select name="id" id="t" selected="<?php echo $Sheets ?>">
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5;$i++)
{
 ?>
   <option value="<?php echo "Sheet".$i; ?>"><?php echo "Sheet".$i; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select> 
</form>
```

**metaGeneratePlot.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```

I need to pass value of selected parameter (parameter name) to another form. But above code does not seem to be working.

Comment: Your question is missing some details, because what you post above is proper code for posting and getting posted values.

Comment: Correction, you have no form element named `name`. So your posted code is incomplete or incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch in your element names; You are posting a form element named `id` but are trying to retrieve one named `name`.

Use:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['id'];
?>
```